# Gta 5 PC lag issue

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have been facing lag (FPS drop) issue in GTA5 on PC, I would like to add that my PC meet the recommended requirements mentioned by the game but still I face lag after like 30-35 minutes of game play.

Only resolution I have found is to restart the game but that fixes the lag only for another 20-30 minutes and than the terrible lag is back again.

Any help is appreciated.

Processor -i5 3570k
Ram -8gb
GraphicCard -amd 7850 2gb

Comment: It sounds like a possible memory leak, check your memory usage when it's lagging. I've also heard that alttabbing back and forth fixes lags like that for some people.

Comment: By restarting the game I'm getting like 20-25 minutes of lag free gameplay  and by alt tabbing around 5 minutes.. The memory leak that you are stating how can I perform that check ?

Comment: What do you mean by lag? Low framerate? Input lag? High ping when playing online?

Comment: @eatSt run task manager and check if you're very close to your memory limit (7.5gb or more used out of 8). If that's true, check what's using all the memory, it's possible that all the programs you have running don't add up to the amount that's shown as total usage, that means there's a hidden memory leak, most likely coming from the game, since there's no issues otherwise. Or it might just be something else... Chrome is famous for memory leaks if certain tabs (Facebook especally) are left open for a long time.

Comment: @Studoku By lag I mean FPS Drop which usually happens after a while as I mentioned above and restarting the game fixes it for a short while.

Comment: @Chippies I saw that the RAM usage is around 6.4gb-6.9gb when playing the game and chrome isn't running on the back.  How can I check the hidden memory leak then?

Comment: @eatSt if you're not hitting your RAM limit, then it's probably not a memory leak (even if it was, it wouldn't affect performance until you hit the limit), so you can most likely rule that out. Do you have either cpu or gpu overclocked? You should check the temperatures for both of them while running the game, might be a throttling issue. You can check the temperatures with software like hwmonitor by cpuid.

Comment: @Chippies Neither CPU nor GPU is overclocked, while playing the game the GPU temp range is 60-75 degree c and CPU temp range is 65-80 degree c. Varies on account of room temperature and yes the CPU has a stock Intel Cooler.

Comment: 80 degrees celsius, while not extreme, it is quite high for a CPU and coupled with a cheaper motherboard could mean either your cpu or your motherboard voltage regulator is throttling. Ideally, you should use a program that can log cpu temperature and clock frequency over time, that way you could see if it is indeed throttling and dropping frequency whenever it hits 80 degrees. If you can, find out what the temperature of the socket is as well, because it can get hotter than the cpu itself.

Comment: I had a similar problem before some years. I used a utility to control my ram called "TuneUp Utilities". Look if you have a program in the Taskbar on the south-east of your desktop. I had the exact same problem back then with GTA SA. I was able to play around 1 mission and then I needed to restart the game since everything began to lag extremely.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, tried many "fixes" out there and only one  worked, I found it in a [steam forum's post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/271590/discussions/0/613956964585407990/).

So this is only for `AMD Graphics Card` users which is our case.

I was using the most recent and stable Catalyst Control Center driver version 14.12, you must uninstall that and install the most recent `beta` Catalyst Control Center driver which is version 15.4, available at [AMD's site here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download).

I also did change GTA 5.exe and GTA 5's launcher to be executable as administrator but I don't think that did change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Update to GTA V PC Patch 1.28.01 .

Update corrected an issue where framerate could drop at various times during gameplay.

And

Check [Fix Lag in GTA 5](http://dexteroid.com/gaming/how-to-fix-fps-lag-and-stutter-in-gta-5/)

Answer (score -1):

Check your system for a bitcoin miner.

You probably downloaded GTA V illegaly, and downloaded a bitcoin miner along with it. I know because I did the same. Although I deleted the illegal version and bought an original one, the bitcoin miner was still active on my PC. It was called MDM.exe. About 10 minutes after launching the game it was scheduled to start automatically.

What it does, besides mining for bitcoins, is eat up your GPU load, with as result that your graphics card cannot render the game as it should anymore. I read the solution here: http://www.reddit.com/r/feedthebeast/comments/330e12/mdm_32bit_what_is_it_and_why/

Good luck!